# How do I perform multiple async calls to a ASP.Net webservice from .NET Winforms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, web-services

I would like to use my webservice but I can't seem to call multiple async functions... Other than cascading from one AsyncCompleted to start another??

Imports picklists.MyWebService

Public Class main

```
Dim WithEvents ws As New picklists.MyWebService.picklists

Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ws.GetCustomersAsDatatableAsync()
    ws.GetRoutesAsDatatableAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub ws_GetCustomersAsDatatableCompleted(sender As Object, e As GetCustomersAsDatatableCompletedEventArgs) Handles ws.GetCustomersAsDatatableCompleted

    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(e.Result, DataTable)

    cmb_customer.DataSource = dt
    cmb_customer.DisplayMember = "NAME"

End Sub

Private Sub ws_GetRoutesAsDatatableCompleted(sender As Object, e As GetRoutesAsDatatableCompletedEventArgs) Handles ws.GetRoutesAsDatatableCompleted

    Dim dt As DataTable = CType(e.Result, DataTable)

    cmb_route.DataSource = dt
    cmb_route.DisplayMember = "NAME"

End Sub
```

Innerexception:
**{"There was an error during asynchronous processing. Unique state object is required for multiple asynchronous simultaneous operations to be outstanding."}**

**EDIT/SOLUTION**:

```
Imports picklists.MyWebService

Public Class main

    Dim WithEvents ws As New picklists.MyWebService.picklists

    Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        ws.GetCustomersAsDatatableAsync(Guid.NewGuid.ToString)
        ws.GetRoutesAsDatatableAsync(Guid.NewGuid.ToString)

    End Sub

    Private Sub ws_GetCustomersAsDatatableCompleted(sender As Object, e As GetCustomersAsDatatableCompletedEventArgs) Handles ws.GetCustomersAsDatatableCompleted

        Dim g As String = e.UserState

        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(e.Result, DataTable)

        cmb_customer.DataSource = dt
        cmb_customer.DisplayMember = "NAME"

    End Sub

    Private Sub ws_GetRoutesAsDatatableCompleted(sender As Object, e As GetRoutesAsDatatableCompletedEventArgs) Handles ws.GetRoutesAsDatatableCompleted

        Dim g As String = e.UserState

        Dim dt As DataTable = CType(e.Result, DataTable)

        cmb_route.DataSource = dt
        cmb_route.DisplayMember = "NAME"

    End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code. What exactly can't you implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.windows-tech.info/13/145e1fa7cf14447c.php) is some article with good c# example of this problem.
It states, that you should pass a unique state object to async method.

```
ws.GetCustomersAsDatatableAsync(System.Guid.NewGuid())
ws.GetRoutesAsDatatableAsync(System.Guid.NewGuid())
```

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, but I don't fully understand how to implement that answer in my solution. The function calls require no parameter, how should I pass a GUID/State object?